# On handling long source names

Tags: bibliographies, citing, source

I am using apalike bibliography style and natbib for citations.

When citing "Board of Governors of the Federal Reserve" I faced the issue that the full source wasn't cited but only "Bord of Governors of". I thought I could solve this Issue by using the official abbreviation FRB, but now my Bibliography only uses the first letter of my sources "name", see image below. Is there a better way to handle long sources?

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: Issue]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: "Board of Governors of the Federal Reserve" is a good example of a *corporate* author name. To keep BibTeX from trying to extract the first-name, von, and last-name components, encase it in a pair of curly braces. I.e., write `author = "{Board of Governors of the Federal Reserve System}"` for the BibTeX entry in question.

Comment: That worked well, thank you.